# How to move a rectangle to a random location when I click the surface of the rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, paint, mouselistener

I really tried hard yesterday to understand the actionlistener. But It only worked with JComponent. Would you mind to give me some examples of moving the location of a rectangle?
I know how to override a frame and a panel class. But I don't get the actionlistener thing. 
On the Java API, It says panel can call a method addmouselistener and we can also pass the argument to the method. I have no idea what (MouseListener l) is. By the way, What is the different between actionlistener and other listener like ( addmouselistener ).

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Littlegame{

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Frame s = new Frame();
}
 }
class Frame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public Frame()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Little Game");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Panel a =new Panel();
        f.add(a);   
        f.setSize(500,400);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}


class Panel extends JPanel{

     public Panel()
     {
         setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.green));

     }
     public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
     {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(150, 150, 30, 30);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(150,150,30,30);
     }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
     {

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a read through [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html).

Your `actionPerformed` method will do nothing, not because you've not attached to anything that would produce an `ActionEvent`, but because you've actually not implemented the `ActionListener` interface.  Take a look at [How to write an action listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).

The long and short of it is.

- Add a `MouseListener` to `Panel`.
- When `mousePressed` (or `mouseReleased` or `mouseClicked`, depending on your needs) is called, use the `MouseEvent` to determine the location that the event took place.
- Record the location of the `MouseEvent` in some instance variable
- Call `repaint`
- When `paintComponent` is called, use the instance variables that record the location of the `MouseEvent` and update the rectangle.

You may also want to have a read through [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to read the link you gave me above.
The website has some examples that I don't understand at all.
I will try anyways